# What is a characteristic subspace (w.r.t a linear operator)?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, linear-transformations

I am working through a book on linear operators and, in the context of a subspace being invariant under an operator, they mention "characteristic subspaces".

```
"All characteristic subspaces of an operator are invariant"
```

The book never defined such a term, and a quick google search didn't really provide me with a formal definition. I assume it is related to characteristic functions in some way?

Comment: Where in what book?

Comment: The only thing that came up from a search of the exact quote was a book that defines it on page 92. https://books.google.com/books?id=i3Pj1NbgtTYC&lpg=PA97&ots=69K9zYwjkT&dq=%22All%20characteristic%20subspaces%20of%20an%20operator%20are%20invariant%22&pg=PA92#v=snippet&q=regular&f=false.  Please include sources when asking about how terminology is used in a particular reference.  Could you please confirm whether the linked book is the one you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, especially in the context of ODEs, the equation $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ is called the "characteristic equation" of $A$, the eigenvalues (which are the solutions of this equation) are called the "characteristic values" and the eigenspaces are called the "characteristic spaces". This makes sense in the context of your quote as indeed the eigenspaces are invariant subspaces.

Comment: The eigenspaces are just an specific case of characteristic space. To give you a counter example, if we consider the usual vector space on $\mathrm{R}^2$, and the enfomorphism $f(x,y) = (x+y,y)$, the has a single eigenvalue equal to $1$ and the eigenspace is $v=(x,0)$. However the minimal polynomial is $1-t$ and the associated endomorphism is $\mathrm{id}-f(x,y)=(y,0)$. We have that this endomorphism applied twice is the null endomorphism, and so the characteristic subspace would be $V$ instead of only the associated eigenspace. That's because I chose a non diagonalizable endomorphism.

Comment: @ManuelPena: You might be correct in your interpretation that the characteristic spaces are the generalized eigenspaces (or even the invariant subspaces associated to the prime factors, be they linear or not) and not the eigenspaces, but since the OP did not include the name of the textbook he used, I don't really know... I've answered the question to the best of my knowledge given what the OP wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Given a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$  and an a fixed endomorphism $f\in \mathrm{End}\left(V\right)$ we can define an homomorphism between the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{K}\left[t\right]$ and the vector space of endomorphisms $\mathrm{End}\left(V\right)$:

$$\mathbb{K}\left[t\right]\ni\varphi(t)=a_0 + a_1t+\dots a_nt^n\mapsto\phi(f)=a_0\mathrm{id}+a_1f+\dots a_nf^n$$
where $\mathrm{id}$ stands for the identity endomorphism and $f^n=\underset{n \text{ times}}{f\circ f\circ\dots\circ f}$.

The minimal polynomial associated to $f$ is a polynomial $\phi_\mathrm{m}(t)$ such that:

- $\phi_\mathrm{m}\left(f\right)=0$ (that is, the associated endomorphism is the zero endomorphism)
- every other polynomial $\varphi(t)$ such that $\varphi\left(f\right)=0$ is a multiple of $\phi_\mathrm{m}(t)$.

This minimal polynomial can be factored in prime polynomials in general, i.e. $1-t^2=(1+t)(1-t)$

If $p(t)$ is one of this prime factors of the minimal polynomial, then the associated characteristic subspace $V_p$ is defined as:

$$
V_p = \left\lbrace v\in\mathrm{Ker}\left(p^k\left(f\right)\right),\text{ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$}\right\rbrace
$$
that is $$V_p = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty\mathrm{Ker}\left(p^k\left(f\right)\right)$$

So there you have it, that is a characteristic subspace.

Are they $f$-invariant? yes. Why? because if $v\in\mathrm{Ker}\left(\varphi\left(f\right)\right)$ then $f(v)\in\mathrm{Ker}\left(\varphi\left(f\right)\right)$. Ask if you need me to elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

In the French speaking community, the notion of "Characteristic subspace" (=sous-espace caractéristique) is taught in every advanced textbook on linear algebra. Linguistically, it corresponds to the notion of "generalised eigenspace" in the US textbooks:

[https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous-espace_caractéristique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous-espace_caract%C3%A9ristique) (in French)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector

For the book you are referring too, I suspect either a poor translation, or a foreign author not fully aware of the subtleties of the mathematical English language ;-).